# .Net Core 2.1 custom middleware issue with Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core-middleware

I have written a piece of custom middleware to check whether or not a user has a specific claim (required to use the application).  If the user doesn't I return a 422 Unprocessable.  I have noticed though that if I don't supply a token I receive a 422 and not a 401. If I check the IsAuthenticated property on the custom middleware it's false when you don't supply a token and true if you do.

Below is my Configure from Startup.cs.  You will notice that the UseAuthentication() happens before the UseClaimsValidationMiddleware() (my custom middleware).

My understanding of the request pipeline was that

1. Authentication would fire.  If the user isn't authenticated (bearer token (jwt) using Auth0) then the middleware would short circuit and return a 401.
2. If the user was authenticated it would hit my custom middleware and check if the claims exist.  If they don't the middleware will short circuit the request and return a 422.
3. If the claims do exist it will pass onto the UseMvc() middleware and actually run the app.

I'm really confused as to why this happening, any ideas/pointers would be greatly appreciated :)

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseSwagger();

        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Test");
            c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
        });

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseClaimsValidationMiddleware();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Comment: You are not correct on point 1) - The authentication returns an "Authentication.NoResult" for a missing token and does not shortcut.  The 401 result happens later when the controller is hit and the asp.net MVC engine filter checks for authentication (usually based on the [Authorize] or [Anonymous] attributes or a policy).  They do this to allow multiple authentication providers in the pipeline (if you had JWT and Basic auth for instance).  So it passes to your middleware, (and if you want to trigger code, the context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated would be false)

Comment: Thank you very much, that’s really helped! I’m going to check for Authentication.NoResult in my middleware and act accordingly. Thanks for clearing this up for me.

Comment: A similar issue could occur if your token has expired so as suggested one can check for IsAuthenticated property of user. I coded for one such scenario where user can have the cookie or pass the bearer header. Added cookie as default auth mechanism and created another Handler/Middleware for taking care of Auth header.